# How do i share kivy app with apple workmates

Tags: python, android, ios, kivy

I've been writing apps for work in python and exporting the relevant ones to my android phone with kivy. When I need to use the script on a windows computer, I ease the transition with WINE. Mac and iPhone friends "want a copy". I really don't have much at stake in this, just don't want to look unhelpful. So what process has worked for others (without TOO much distraction)?

Is there an emulator?
Do I borrow their phone and laptop for a couple days?
Can I buy a cheap old mac and an iPhone with a cracked screen and hack away? (And are there generation issues that will make this unhelpful.)

We aren't talking about brand new apps. These are a few months old, so I wont be debugging so much as installing. I have however concluded that the transition from a kivy app running on linux through buildozer to my own phone is much harder than it looks.

or maybe just smile, buy them a beer, and offer them the python source code while muttering something about Steve Jobs...

I do know that EVERYBODY has had this problem. What solutions?

Comment: For iOS, you will need a paid developer program membership (US$99) so that may be enough for you to say, "sorry, I can't". Once you have that you can create ad-hoc builds using their device identifiers that you can then send them to install via drag and drop (these will stop working after a few months), you can use TestFlight (requires some Apple review but not full release review).  TestFlight builds also expire but you can update and they can reinstall more easily or you can try for full App Store release. You will need a Mac (or you can try and runs hackintosh VM) to do any of this.

Comment: Your question also mentions Mac; this is much easier than iOS since macOS is a Unix derivative. Your python code will probably just run as-is and there is no need for a developer program membership. Supporting macOS is probably much easier than supporting Windows.

Comment: Perfect solution. "Lend me your phone and give this guy a Benjamin, and I'll do my best." Thanks.